# Web Api and external event handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I've got a windows service, and I want to expose a web api on this service so our users can interact with the service via http.

I understand how to do a self host web api (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api), now my main problem is how to interface my ApiController with the class it will be executed from, so that when an http request is processed, an event is triggered, and something happens outside of the ApiController.

Based on the following example, how can I register my event handler UserRegistered in my service class ?

**Web API Controller**

```
public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        public delegate void OnPostRegister(Profile user);

        public event OnPostRegister UserRegistered;

        public void PostStream(Profile user)
        {
            try
            {
                IProfileBuilder builder = new ProfileBuilder();
                builder.RegisterProfile(user);

                if (UserRegistered!= null)
                {
                    UserRegistered(user);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new HttpException(500, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

**Service Class**

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //initialize web api
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
        }

        //Load registered profiles
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can access the instance of the controller to subscribe to an event directly; I think you probably want a loosely coupled event handler; I was going to suggest the EventAggregator but that is part of Prism which is more for WPF although you could extract it. I did find this which looks like it could solve your issue.

http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2011/07/28/loosely-coupled-events-in-net-and-harvesting-open-source-projects/

Comment: I accepted your answer, although I went with a simpler approach. This approach seems cleaner, but what I did is use a singleton static class. I instantiated it when my service starts, and when my controller need to interact with the rest of my service, I call the various methods in the singleton, which by keeps state of several moving parts of my application.

Comment: Hey there, guiomie. Could you please provide some code with your approach?

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry but you don't understand the concepts that stays behind web apis and cooperation with other services\apps in .NET world. You can not do like this: calling .NET event to trigger external service - it's crazy idea.
You have few choices here:
A) service bus - which pass events from web api to external service to handle it (NServiceBus, RabitMQ);
B) delegate processing to HangeFire;
C) any custom mechanism to inform external system about web api event\change (db triggers or any shitty ideas that will be difficult to maintain in the end like you are trying to do now)
D) you can create library with the logic from your super windows service and create API for it and you can create HTTP client to call call this API from anywhere - even you could refactor your old service.

Http processing has to be fast and simple. Delegation of the complex tasks should go to other services via additional mechanism\technology and not via .NET event. It is against going practices and impractical from many point of views.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "interface my ApiController with the class it will be executed from, so that when an http request is processed, an event is triggered" - it's crazy idea. Singleton that calls some existing service method -crazy idea. Controllers in ASP.NET world works by convention and routing on the level of middleware. You don't care about that. You can interact with middleware by registering FILTERS. Check in Google: .NET FILTERS ;-)